# Ruby on Rails and Twilio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

After following [instruction](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html) on how to integrate `Twilio` in ROR apps, I have an issues when making a `curl` request:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/twilio/voice -d 'foo=bar'
```

Return me:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: localhost not working in twilio as callback. Please use ngrok with port 3000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like your `/twilio/voice` path is lying behind some user authentication. Your controller is being interrupted and sending you to the sign in page instead. You probably don't want user authentication in front of your Twilio routes.

Comment: I found a solution that `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :authenticate_user!` enable to request a curl. Thanks!!

Comment: Great! If the answer helped, please do mark it as correct so that it can help others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your app seems to require login before using the service. If you are trying to check using `curl` , please disable `sign_in` check. After testing you can enable it again.